# How to inject DbContext implementation into Prism ViewModel constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, prism

I'm working on a WPF Prism application using Unity and Entity Framework. I'm looking to inject my custom DbContext while constructing ViewModels, so I can use it through the life of the ViewModel. The module that the DbContext class is in gets registered in the Bootstrapper, and the DbContext type gets registered during Module.Initialize().

With all that said, a runtime error is getting thrown when trying to construct ViewModels that inject the DbContext. It's saying that IDbConnection needs to be registered. When I register it with the module it then says that DbConnection is an abstract class and can't be constructed. There must be something I'm not aware of concerning how a DbContext is supposed to be registered.

Here's where the type is being registered in the module:

```
public class SharedResourcesModule : IModule
{
    IUnityContainer container;


    public SharedResourcesModule(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }


    public void Initialize()
    {
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
        container.RegisterType<IDataBaseContext, EFDbContext>();
    }
}
```

And an example of the ViewModel constructor:

```
public class ProductContextResultViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ProductContextResultViewModel(IDataBaseContext dataBaseContext)
    {
        this.DataBaseContext = dataBaseContext as EFDbContext;
    }


    private EFDbContext DataBaseContext { get; set; }
}
```

If there's any other detail I can provide please let me know!

**Exception detail below**:

Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type Object, key "ProductContextResultView"
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 53
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 103
       at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionNavigationContentLoader.CreateNewRegionItem(String candidateTargetContract)
  InnerException: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "System.Object", name = "ProductContextResultView".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, is an abstract class and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving ContextResultsPane.ProductContextResult.ProductContextResultView,ProductContextResultView (mapped from System.Object, ProductContextResultView)
  Resolving parameter "viewModel" of constructor ContextResultsPane.ProductContextResult.ProductContextResultView(ContextResultsPane.ProductContextResult.ProductContextResultViewModel viewModel)
    Resolving ContextResultsPane.ProductContextResult.ProductContextResultViewModel,(none)
    Resolving parameter "dataBaseContext" of constructor ContextResultsPane.ProductContextResult.ProductContextResultViewModel(SharedResources.DataAccess.IDataBaseContext dataBaseContext)
      Resolving SharedResources.DataAccess.EFDbContext,(none) (mapped from SharedResources.DataAccess.IDataBaseContext, (none))
      Resolving parameter "connection" of constructor SharedResources.DataAccess.EFDbContext(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection)
        Resolving System.Data.Common.DbConnection,(none)

```
   Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
   NameRequested=ProductContextResultView
   TypeRequested=Object
   StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
        at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
        at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)
        at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.UnityServiceLocatorAdapter.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
        at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49
   InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
        HResult=-2146233079
        Message=The current type, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, is an abstract class and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
        Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
        StackTrace:
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructAbstractClass(IBuilderContext context)
             at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)
             at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)
             at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)
             at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)
             at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)
             at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)
             at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
             at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
        InnerException:
```

Comment: It appears that upon trying to resolve the DbContext, Unity is using a constructor that requires a DbConnection. Unity needs to know which implementation of DbConnection you want to use.

Comment: You're right, there is a constructor for DbContext that passes in a DbConnection; I completely forgot I added it! After doing more reading it turns out that Unity uses the most verbose constructor, even though I wanted it to use the default constructor. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glen Thomas' guidance helped point me to doing some more reading, and it turns out that Unity uses the most verbose constructor by default. This is the core of the problem, since I had a constructor that required a DbConnection to be passed for unit testing.

In order to force Unity to use the default constructor I changed this...

```
container.RegisterType<IDataBaseContext, EFDbContext>();
```

...to this...

```
container.RegisterType<IDataBaseContext, EFDbContext>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

After the change it's working as intended!